MQ client (amqputc) getting "MQCONNX ended with reason code 2393" when connecting TLS enabled queue
Want to check what is wrong with my configuration.

Installed the MQ and created the queue using mq-dev-config.mqsc.

created a root, server and a client certificate for enabling TLS.

I am using the DEV.APP.SVRCONN channel.

Created the certificates in /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/ssl location and added all three certificates (server, client and root) in it.

After restart, the queue manager is picking the location and i can see the SSLKEYR(/var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/ssl/key) and CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremqqm1) pointing correctly.

below are the channel side changes

Altered the DEV.APP.SVRCONN to use SSLCIPH(ANY_TLS12)  SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) CERTLABL('')
removed CONNAUTH at queue manager
Added back-stop channel authentication rule
Allow connection if it match (SSLPEER('CN=mqclient,O=mq,C=us') SSLCERTI('CN=ca-rootca'))


I am able to connect the queue using java client.

When using amqputc, i am getting the error

AMQ9636E: SSL distinguished name does not match peer name, channel 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN'



CCDT file, mqclient.ini file, channel CHLAUTH settings is in the below screenshot:




Where did you put the client side kdb file?  What label did you give the client cert in the client's kdb? How are you telling amqsputc the connection details?

I added the client kdb in mq server but in a different location. i am invoking client using a separate user --> Added "SecurityPolicy=UserExternal" in the qm.ini and authoruize that user as well.

AMQ9639E error message contains a bit more information. Could you edit your question and include the full EXPLANATION section as well. Then we'll be able to see what it is matching against what.

What label did you give the client cert in the client's kdb? How are you telling amqsputc the connection details and client kdb location?

in the client kdb, the label is ibmwebspheremqapp. while invoking, i am using "export MQCERTLABL=ibmwebspheremqapp". Also the amqssslc is working fine.

It sounds like the answer to the question I've asked twice that you didn't answer is that you are using the MQSERVER environment variable to specify the connection details to amqputc.  You can't specify the cipher with MQSERVER,  you will need to use a channel table if your want to have amqputc use a TLS channel.

HI @Morag, i am getting the below error.
link

HI @Joshc
i am passing the mqclient_cert.ini through environment variable MQCLNTCF. In the mqclient_cert.ini, i am passing the CCDT file path where i have the certificatePeerName,cipherSpecification and certificateLabel defined. In the mqclient_cert.ini, i have the SSLKeyRepository location defined , for the key.kdb file. It is able to read the location but for some reason, it's only reading a wrong certificate.

According to the error message CN=mqserver is the DN of the certificate and that wouldn't match CN=mqclient that you have set.

Hi @Morag, that's what i am not sure why mqserver is picked up? i am sending "certificatePeerName": "CN=mqclient,O=mq,C=us" in my ccdt file.

Please update the question with the contents of your CCDT file. You last comment suggests that you have coded the client side channel definition with the client side certificate DN which is why it doesn't match. I will write up an answer to fully explain but would appreciate the update to the question so I am sure of what you are doing.

Thanks @Morag. I have added the screenshots of the CCDT and mqclient.ini file in the link

Ok - so I can see that your CCDT coded certificatePeerName: CN=server, but, as the error message says, the queue manager presented a certificate with CN=mqserver. These do not match and so the channel does not start.

When connecting an MQ Client application, e.g. amqsputc, to a queue manager using mutual TLS there is a certificate at each end and there can be a peer name check at each end.
A peer name check is when you supply a pattern to match against the certificate Distinguished Name (DN) to ensure that you are indeed communicating with the correct entity. While a certificate may be supplied that is valid, you might want to go one step further and ensure that this is a certificate that identifies the correct entity.
Queue Manager side
To have the queue manager end of the channel check the client's certificate's DN, you supply this pattern either on the SVRCONN channel definition or in a CHLAUTH rule (preferred).
So assuming the client certificate DN is CN=mqclient, we would imagine a CHLAUTH rule something like:-
SET CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) TYPE(SSLPEERMAP) +
    SSLPEER('CN=mqclient') +
    USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER('clntusr') 

If the client presented a certificate to the queue manager with a DN containing CN=mqclient then it would be allowed to run and would be assigned to run with the user id of clntusr.
Client side
To have the client end of the channel check the queue manager's certificate's DN, you supply this pattern on the CLNTCONN definition in the CCDT.
So assuming the queue manager certificate DN is CN=mqserver, we would imagine a CLNTCONN definition something like:-
DEFINE CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) +
       CONNAME('edx2(1414)') SSLCIPH(ANY_TLS12) +
       SSLPEER('CN=mqserver')

If the queue manager presented a certificate to the client with a DN containing CN=mqserver then the connection would be allowed to proceed.
If, however, you mix these up, and say, code SSLPEER('CN=mqclient') in your client side CCDT, then the match is going to fail, and error message AMQ9636E will be reported.
If they simply don't match because you coded SSLPEER('CN=server') in your client side CCDT and the queue manager presented a certificate with a DN containing CN=mqserver then error message AMQ9636E will also be reported.

you are the best. "CN=server" was a typo. I was originally trying "CN=mqclient" and was getting this error. After just changing the certificatePeerName to "CN=mqserver" , it started working. Thanks a lot.
